# Increasing the obstacle detection range in costmap ROS2 Foxy

Tags: ros2, costmap, nav2

I am running Nav2 Foxy version in my self build navigation robot.
The whole system works without any issue and now i am trying to tune some parameter in the costmap to increase the obstacle detection range.
As you can see in the picture below, the laser scan near top left of the robot are not recgonised as an obstacle in the costmap. The detection range seems to be limited by a certain circular range represented as the white grid in the costmap. [image]

I am looking for a way to increase this range so that my robot can detect obstacles furthur away. I suspect that the obstacle layer parameter in nav2.yaml file might have something to do with this. I tried to tune the obstacle_max_range parameter but nothing has changed. I would really appreciate some insights for this matter.

```
  obstacle_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
    enabled: True
    observation_sources: scan
    scan:
      topic: /scan
      max_obstacle_height: 10.0
      clearing: True
      marking: True
      inf_is_valid : False
      data_type: "LaserScan"
      raytrace_max_range: 200.0
      raytrace_min_range: 0.0
      obstacle_max_range: 190.0
      obstacle_min_range: 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Foxy version used different parameter name. in Foxy its obstacle_range and raytrace_range rather than obstacle_max_range and raytrace_max_range.